# Another datetime to GMT conversion question

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am pulling a feed from Google Calendar.  It has the event start time in this format:

```
StartDate: 2011-06-25T18:00:00.000-05:00
```

I understand that the -05:00 is the timezone offset.  I need the above to get put into the mySQL database in GMT time.  I was just reading about [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [gmdate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) but I'm afraid I'm pretty new at this and I don't seem to be getting the results I need.

Right now the above code ends up being this in my datetime colum in mySQL:

```
2011-06-25 18:00:00
```

I need the above to be:

```
2011-06-25 23:00:00
```

But I need a dynamic way to do this so any user with a different timezone will get the correct results-IE: I need the function to be smart enough to read the timezone offset and make the needed changes regardless of the offset.  I'm hoping there is a PHP function that does this already?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use strtotime, you can do this:

```
<?
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = strtotime('2011-06-25T18:00:00.000-05:00');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
```

This results on my system in:

```
2011-06-25 23:00:00
```

Comment: I seem to just be getting a string of what to me seem like random numbers when doing strtotime($StartDate).  Can you share your code to get the above result?

Comment: Sorry, my bad: I didn't include a newline before the code, so the php didn't show :D. strtotime does indeed give you 'random' numbers (seconds since 1 jan. 1970, aka unix time epoch). You can then use that in the various date functions, or save it in a timestamp field. In this case, `date` uses it to format it with the given string. You could also use a php `DateTime` object, etc. Once you have a timestamp your basically free to do anything :)

Comment: hmm.. This still gives me 2011-06-25 18:00:00.  I think I might not be clear enough-I am actually at -5:00 here on my computer, but I need the datetime to be stored in the database at GMT.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will, probably, work:

```
// get date with time zone
$date = new DateTime('2011-06-25T18:00:00.000-05:00');

// get time zone offset in minutes
$offset = $date->getOffset();

// get date without offset
$date2 = new DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'));

// apply offset to get UTC time
$date2->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $offset . 'M'));
```

probably it's a little complicated, but I'm not a "PHP guy", so..

Comment: Oh, from an @Nanne answer I see it's maybe an overkill :)

Comment: Hmm.  I got: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::add()

Comment: @Joel: `DateTime::add()` is a PHP >= 5.3.0 method. If you're on 5.2.x using `DateTime` is somewhat limited. Stick to the `strtotime()`.

Comment: Ah-yeah, my host is using 5.2 still.  Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [`DateTime`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateTimeZone`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) - this is also PHP 5.2.x compatible.

```
$date = new DateTime('2011-06-25T18:00:00.000-05:00');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This solution does not require you to change the configured PHP timezone with [`date.timezone`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) or [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).